# How to obtain an Oauth 2.0 token for Google Ads using REST request?

Tags: oauth2-playground

I'm trying to extract campaign stats data from the google ads API into a desktop ETL process.

I've inherited this process and it's currently using Oauth 2.0 for authentication.

Firstly, is this necessary or can I just use an API key instead?

If I do need to use Oauth, then I'd like to replace the following process with a REST API call.

The following steps are taken to refresh the Oauth bearer token in the Oauth Playground.

1. Authorize the playground URL and then copy and paste the client id and client secret into the playground
2. I then authorize the Adwords API
3. Select my account
4. Click allow
5. Click exchange authorization code for tokens
6. I then can use the Access Token to get the ad data I need into my ETL tool.

If someone could provide an example request for how to get this token outside of the playground, I'd really appreciate it!

Specifically, what headers do I need, http method, url, body and any other info that might help.

As for trying to replace the Oauth Bearer token with the API key, I've tried replacing the "Authorization" header with a "key" header and using the key in place of the Bearer token.

That just gives me the following 401 - "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.